# Easyadmin redirect after update or save rows

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I can't find a way to redirect after saving or updating a record. it always redirects me to index(list of records). Easy admin symfony.

Thanks.

Tried using a subscriber or overriding the update entity method but no result

Answer (score 1):

You can use method [AbstractCrudController::getRedirectResponseAfterSave](https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/blob/3.x/src/Controller/AbstractCrudController.php#L597)
 in your Crud Controller.

For example:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use App\Entity\Tag;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Action;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Context\AdminContext;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractCrudController;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Router\AdminUrlGenerator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class TagCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return Tag::class;
    }

    protected function getRedirectResponseAfterSave(AdminContext $context, string $action): RedirectResponse
    {
        /** @var Tag $tag */
        $tag = $context->getEntity()->getInstance();
        $adminUrlGenerator = $this->container->get(AdminUrlGenerator::class);

        if ($tag->isPublic() && $tag->isEditable()) {
            $url = $adminUrlGenerator
                ->setAction(Action::EDIT)
                ->setEntityId($tag->getId())
                ->generateUrl()
            ;

            return $this->redirect($url);
        }

        if ($tag->isPublic()) {
            return $this->redirect('https://google.com');
        }

        return parent::getRedirectResponseAfterSave($context, $action);
    }
}
```